# Find the first day of last month in every quarter in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, dateadd

I have data of every day with a format like this '2020-01-01'. How do I accurately locate the first day of last month in every quarter in a database?

Here is what have so far:

```
Where
   d3.[day_date] > DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    and d3.[day_date] < DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: So are you storing your dates as varchars then? And is or isn't working about your current query? Sample data + expected results would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: Please don't add tag names to the question title. The site handles that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your query to get the first day of the last month of quarters as given below:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0)) -- two quarters before last month
SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0  )) --  previous quarter last month
SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) -- current quarter last month
SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0)) -- next quarter last month
```

```
2021-03-01 00:00:00.000
2021-06-01 00:00:00.000
2021-09-01 00:00:00.000
2021-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year(day_date),
                     ceiling(month(day_date) / 3.0) * 3,
                     1)
```

If you wanted this for every date in your table, you can use:

```
select distinct datefromparts(year(day_date),
                              ceiling(month(day_date) / 3.0) * 3,
                              1) as yyyyqq
from t;
```